# Understanding SSH private and public keys with PuTTYgen

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-keys

I used PuTTy keygen to create a public key. I copied the public key into `david.pub` and sent to developer who put the key on server(vps), so i can clone a repository.  When i created the public key i typed a password.  When i attempt to clone this happens:

`$ git clone my_app:money_app.git new_money_app
Cloning into 'new_money_app'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/User1/.ssh/david.pub':`

I type the password i set and this line is repeated 3 times `Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/User1/.ssh/david.pub':`

Then after this is displayed

```
 Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The repository exists.  This is how my config file looks:

```
Host my_app
User git
HostName xx.xx.xxx.xx
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/david.pub
```

How do i solve this so i can clone the repository?   I'm completely new to GIT, do i need to recreate the public key?  I was told to create a public key, do i need a private key also?

I'm a front end developer, so this is quite confusing.

Comment: A public key without a private key is quite useless. I suggest you read parts of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a Git problem, it's just ssh.  You can debug the problem more easily by trying to ssh into the machine.  `ssh my_app` should give you the same problem.

A public key should not have a password, that should tip you off there is something wrong.  It's asking you over and over again because you're putting in a password that the key does not have.  Your *private key* has the password.

In ssh there are two keys, the public one (`~/.ssh/david.pub`) and the private one (`~/.ssh/david`).  You can't have made a public key without a private one.  The private key is your secret, it stays with you, and it should be password protected in case it is stolen.  The public key goes on the servers you wish to log into.  The private key is used to unlock things encrypted with the public one (and vice-versa).

The problem is this line:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/david.pub
```

This should be your *private key*, `~/.ssh/david`.

Comment: Thanks!  i forgot to make a private key.  WIth PuTTy keygen can i load the public key(i downloaded it) and generate a private key from it?  Or do i have to generate both keys again?

Comment: @user892134 If you could make a private key from a public key that would defeat the point of having a public key. You'll have to make them again. You cannot make a public key without a private one, however [PuTTygen](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen) makes you save them separately, which makes no sense and it's probably how you got into this problem in the first place.